# Why do a small amount of add/deletes take several seconds in EF4?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-4, code-first

Using the Entity Framework 4. I have created a Code First database in the past and a piece of code needs to delete and add 16 objects, this takes 6 seconds each. That's 300+ ms for each query!

The deletes/adds occur in a `foreach` scope and there is a `SaveChanges()` outside the `foreach`.

[image]

In the above image you see that each takes 6 seconds, which is 34% of the time, for 16 calls.

That doesn't sound normal to me... **Why is this and how can I improve the performance?**

If there is no solution: Are there any workarounds I can use? It would be a pain to rewrite my project...

Comment: Please post some code, and 34% of what? At least add an outline of the classes and the exact code (around/of) this foreach loop.

Comment: Both are 70%, it doesn't matter what the other 30% is. No need for code...

Comment: you realize that each of those 16 deletes will be a seperate query - that's probably why it's slow. If your deleting so many records you should use a SPROC so it's only 1 hop to the server.

Comment: I already figured out how to access the ObjectContext and thus the ExecuteStoreCommand, is there any guide on how to execute a stored procedure in a Code First setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd advise you to try something like [EF Profiler](http://efprof.com/). I think there's a free trial, which allows you to try it out. Basically, with it you can see what kind of things are happening internally with your EF app.

Another point to note: Is this by chance a web application? In my own project I found that when I ran the app in Cassini (built-in visual studio webserver) things were pretty slow. Moving over to IIS 7 suddenly made everything a hell of a lot faster. It's not hard to do either, provided you have IIS installed.
Simply go to the properties of your web project, go to the 'Web' tab and toggle 'Use Local IIS Web server'. It will also allow you to create a virtual directory from here, so there's no need for managing IIS directly.

Other than that, I don't think there's much to be said about your problem, as we don't have any sample code. It could be that your 16 objects actually produce a lot of queries, because of related entities or something. EF Profiler will show that though.

---

Addition:
Another thing to be aware of is that EF isn't really meant for bulk actions. IF you need to do a lot of updating/deleting/inserting at once you'd be better off with something else I think.

I know 16 entities is not bulk (yet), but I figured I'd put this little notion in here anyway.

Comment: Yes, I am on Cassini and will try IIS 7 next time I continue developing. Will it still allow me to get debugging information? For EF Profiler I get the following exception at the db.SaveChanges() line: Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Comment: For support on EF profile you should contact Ayende (the one who made it). He's quite supportive I found.

Comment: About IIS and debugging: It works just like you're used to. That's the beauty, it just works out of the box. It'll probably give some errors when creating a virtual directory via visual studio, but it will say that you need to install some component, which is installable via the control panel (like all windows components).

Comment: IIS 7 gives an improvement in overall performance, thank you for that! But the query execution performance doesn't seem to improve. What is a better alternative to insert/update/remove multiple items? SQL, Stored Procedures, ...? How do I do this? I don't have experience with other data access than through Code First. But I do know SQL and the Stored Procedures concept...

Comment: @TomWij: I think the question is: is this something that happens a lot, or only once or twice per session/day/week. Do you have to optimize it?
Either way, did you get EF profiler working yet? You need to figure out which queries are being run. For all we know, maybe your table structure is sub optimal, or there's a lot of referenced stuff that needs updating/deleting per entity.

Comment: Well, we need to update a price list daily. But if 16 articles take 6 or 12 second (depending on the delete), then all our articles will take an unacceptable amount of time. So yes, it needs to be optimized. No, I can't get the EF profiler to work. There are no references to other objects...

Comment: Ah, after creating the database again and messing around with the connection string I seem to have the EF profiler working. It is giving some alerts which I am trying to resolve now...

Comment: Bingo! Converted my 'filtering based on results' into 'filtering inside a LINQ query' and the whole filter procedure only takes 792 ms to select 16 products out of 30k products by filtering based on two columns... Woohoo, thank you! :D

Comment: So what actually happened? Did your app actually retrieve all 30k products and proceed to filter them in your app instead of retrieving 16 products from the database?

Comment: Yeah, that was what happened.